# NCurses with WSL Displaying Boxes Incorrectly

Tags: c, ncurses, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using ubuntu on my windows computer using the windows subsystem for linux to compile a simple program using ncurses in C that shows a box inside a ncurses window. As seen in the picture below, the  box does not render fully. Is there something wrong with my code or is this an issue within WSL?

[The drawn box displays incorrectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLCFJ.png)
The box should stretch and connect the left and right sides

```
    int main()
{
    initscr();
    noecho();
    cbreak();

    int sizeY, sizeX;
    getmaxyx(stdscr, sizeY, sizeX);

    WINDOW *mainMenu = newwin(10, 10, 5, 10);
    box(mainMenu, 0, 0);
    refresh();
    wrefresh(mainMenu);
    keypad(mainMenu, true);

    getch();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fixed that and updated screenshot

Comment: The program seems fine. If you use a console like mintty or winpty you'll get better VT100 support.

Answer (score 2):

The `getch();` should be `wgetch(mainMenu);`
Otherwise, repainting `stdscr` can wipe out part of the `mainWindow`.

But that does not appear to be the problem shown in the picture.  That's probably using `TERM=xterm` (or `TERM=xterm-256color`) on some terminal that doesn't completely match **xterm**, e.g., the [*repeat*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51904557/how-to-get-a-correctly-sized-window-in-ncurses/51907467#51907467) feature.